# Raw Sql Query for Updating a record in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, razor-pages

I need to update a record in razor pages with mutiple conditions in where clause,

Currently im using this code snippet

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

where the update query will be like this

```
UPDATE [StaffAssets] SET [EmpID] = p0, [IssuedDate] = p1, [IssuedQty] = p2, [LastModifiedBy] = p3, [LastModifiedTimestamp] = p4, [ReturnDate] = p5, [ReturnQty] = p6, [StaffAssetName] = p7 WHERE [StaffID] = p8
```

what i need is

```
UPDATE [StaffAssets] SET [EmpID] = p0, [IssuedDate] = p1, [IssuedQty] = p2, [LastModifiedBy] = p3, [LastModifiedTimestamp] = p4, [ReturnDate] = p5, [ReturnQty] = p6, [StaffAssetName] = p7 **WHERE [StaffID] = p8 AND [EmpID] = p9 AND [StaffAssetsName] = p10**
```

Is there any way to execute this query in Razor Pages?
How to execute raw sql query in razor pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to execute this query in Razor Pages? How to execute raw sql query in razor pages?

To execute raw SQL queries, you can use [`ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlinterpolatedasync?view=efcore-3.1).

```
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"UPDATE [StaffAssets] SET [EmpID] = {p0}, [IssuedDate] = {p1}, [IssuedQty] = {p2}, [LastModifiedBy] = {p3}, [LastModifiedTimestamp] = {p4}, [ReturnDate] = {p5}, [ReturnQty] = {p6}, [StaffAssetName] = {p7} WHERE [StaffID] = {p8} AND [EmpID] = {p9} AND [StaffAssetsName] = {p10}");
```